# C++ Array Of Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In C++ if I want an array of pointers so that I may have them point to different objects at a latter stage what does the syntax look like.

EDIT

I need to clarify what I am trying to do I guess. I have a class foo that has and add method. In the add method I take a reference to class bar. I want to save that reference into a pointer array of bar. The array of pointer bar will need to be expanded all the time this I have no problems with. It is creating and array on the heap of pointers so that I may assign bar objects to them later. What I have tried seems to fail as class bar does not have a default constructor which the compiler is complaining about. This lead me to think that I was creating and array of actual objects which I did not want to do.

Please no stl and no I do not want to hear about how you think this is crazy etc that is your opinion.

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer your question, but in most cases it would be better to use an array of pointers.  e.g. std::vector<BaseObjectType *> collection;

Comment: what is meant by "no actual initialization of foo objects" ? Also, do you know how many elements in the array at compile time itself?

Comment: What code have you produced so far?

Comment: “no stl and no I do not want to hear about how you think this is crazy etc that is your opinion” – you *do* realize how ignorant and condescending at the same time that sounds? You may have good reasons to shun the STL – but why not tell us them to cut all this short?

Answer (score 64):

What you want is:

```
Foo *array[10]; // array of 10 Foo pointers
```

Not to be confused with:

```
Foo (*array)[10]; // pointer to array of 10 Foos
```

In either case, nothing will be automatically initialized because these represent pointers to Foos that have yet to be assigned to something (e.g. with new).

I finally "got" pointer/array declaration syntax in C when I realized that it describes how you access the base type.  `Foo *array[5][10];` means that `*array[0..4][0..9]` (subscript on an array of 5 items, then subscript on an array of 10 items, then dereference as a pointer) will access a Foo object (note that `[]` has higher precedence than `*`).

This seems backwards.  You would think that `int array[5][10];` (a.k.a. `int (array[5])[10];`) is an array of 10 `int array[5]`.  Suppose this were the case.  Then you would access the last element of the array by saying `array[9][4]`.  Doesn't that look backwards too?  Because a C array declaration is a pattern indicating how to get to the base type (rather than a composition of array expressions like one might expect), array declarations and code using arrays don't have to be flipflopped.

Comment: +1 Yes, C declarations actually do make sense once you understand them :)

Comment: For future visitors to this question: You can use a [tool like this](http://cdecl.org/) that translates these declarations into something that resembles English, to get a better understanding of how a variable is declared.

Answer (score 10):

For example, if you want an array of `int` pointers it will be `int* a[10]`. It means that variable `a` is a collection of 10 `int*` s.

**EDIT**

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
class Bar
{
};

class Foo
{
public:

    //Takes number of bar elements in the pointer array
    Foo(int size_in);

    ~Foo();
    void add(Bar& bar);
private:

    //Pointer to bar array
    Bar** m_pBarArr;

    //Current fee bar index
    int m_index;
};

Foo::Foo(int size_in) : m_index(0)
{
    //Allocate memory for the array of bar pointers
    m_pBarArr = new Bar*[size_in];
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    //Notice delete[] and not delete
    delete[] m_pBarArr;
    m_pBarArr = NULL;
}

void Foo::add(Bar &bar)
{
    //Store the pointer into the array. 
    //This is dangerous, you are assuming that bar object
    //is valid even when you try to use it
    m_pBarArr[m_index++] = &bar;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to implement (or declare as private) a copy operator, see [Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722).

Answer (score 4):

I would do it something along these lines:

```
class Foo{
...
};

int main(){
  Foo* arrayOfFoo[100]; //[1]

  arrayOfFoo[0] = new Foo; //[2]
}
```

[1] This makes an array of 100 pointers to Foo-objects. But no Foo-objects are actually created.

[2] This is one possible way to instantiate an object, and at the same time save a pointer to this object in the first position of your array.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use the STL, then the code looks a <s>lot</s> bit like C.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

template< class T >
void append_to_array( T *&arr, size_t &n, T const &obj ) {
    T *tmp = static_cast<T*>( std::realloc( arr, sizeof(T) * (n+1) ) );
    if ( tmp == NULL ) throw std::bad_alloc( __FUNCTION__ );
       // assign things now that there is no exception
    arr = tmp;
    new( &arr[ n ] ) T( obj ); // placement new
    ++ n;
}
```

`T` can be any POD type, including pointers.

Note that `arr` must be allocated by `malloc`, not `new[]`.

Answer (score 2):

boost:ptr_array

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_array.html