# how to create a array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hashtable

I'm trying to create an array of pointers for my hashtable. But I'm having trouble because I keep on getting segmentation faults for my functions(i.e. add, remove, find, delete functions) and I'm not sure if it's because I don't have my array of pointers declared and defined correctly. Here is what I have:

`Node **array = new Node*` is this how you would create a dynamic array of pointers?

Comment: `Node ** array = new Node *[10];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Array Of Pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879700/c-array-of-pointers)

Comment: nope, I think he meant dynamic array of pointers...

Comment: @J3soon yes exactly!! now is this how my private member variable would look:

`Node **array;`?


And my default constructor would be:
`array = new Node*[size]`??

Comment: I wouldn't use anything involving `*` or `new`, or custom destructors.  And therefore I wouldn't have segmentation faults and other such memory errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use :

```
Node **array = new Node*[10];
```

setting the pointer :

```
Node node;
array[0] = &node;
```

and remember to delete :

```
delete[] array;
```